# App installs in Android device and uninstalls itself

Tags: macos, npm-install, appium-android

I could able to run the Android automation one month before in my MAC. But after updating angular js, installing protractor, typescript  etc., softwares, appium automation is not working for Android. App is installing now but within few seconds, it gets uninstalled. What i have observed is Android session is not starting , Please find the logs below and shed some light

```html
2019-02-25 19:51:41:946 [Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.10.0
2019-02-25 19:51:41:947 [Appium] Non-default server args:
2019-02-25 19:51:41:948 [Appium]   address: 127.0.0.1
2019-02-25 19:51:41:948 [Appium]   sessionOverride: true
2019-02-25 19:51:41:948 [Appium]   logFile: /Users/magantimurthy/AppiumServerLogs.txt
2019-02-25 19:51:41:973 [Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
2019-02-25 19:52:14:593 [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
2019-02-25 19:52:14:593 [HTTP] {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/magantimurthy/CCI_Mobile_UI_Tests/src/app-release.apk","rotatable":true,"clearSystemFiles":true,"appWaitActivity":"com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines.MainActivity","apppackage":"com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines","deviceName":"Android","fullReset":true,"appActivity":"com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines.MainActivity","newCommandTimeout":"200000","autoGrantPermissions":"true","takesScreenshot":true,"devicename":"android","eventTimings":true,"platformName":"Android","cssSelectorsEnabled":true},"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"appium:app":"/Users/magantimurthy/CCI_Mobile_UI_Tests/src/app-release.apk","appium:appActivity":"com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines.MainActivity","appium:appWaitActivity":"com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines.MainActivity","apppackage":"com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines","appium:autoGrantPermissions":"true","appium:clearSystemFiles":true,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"appium:deviceName":"Android","devicename":"android","appium:eventTimings":true,"appium:fullReset":true,"appiu
2019-02-25 19:52:14:596 [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"app":"/Users/magantimurthy/CCI_Mobile_UI_Tests/src/app-release.apk","rotatable":true,"clearSystemFiles":true,"appWaitActivity":"com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines.MainActivity","apppackage":"com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines","deviceName":"Android","fullReset":true,"appActivity":"com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines.MainActivity","newCommandTimeout":"200000","autoGrantPermissions":"true","takesScreenshot":true,"devicename":"android","eventTimings":true,"platformName":"Android","cssSelectorsEnabled":true},null,{"alwaysMatch":{"appium:app":"/Users/magantimurthy/CCI_Mobile_UI_Tests/src/app-release.apk","appium:appActivity":"com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines.MainActivity","appium:appWaitActivity":"com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines.MainActivity","apppackage":"com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines","appium:autoGrantPermissions":"true","appium:clearSystemFiles":true,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"appium:deviceName":"Android","devicename":"android","appium:eventTimings":true,"appium:fullReset":true,"appium:newCommandTimeout":"200000","platformName":"android...
2019-02-25 19:52:14:596 [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1551124334596 (13:52:14 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time))
2019-02-25 19:52:14:600 [BaseDriver] The capabilities ["apppackage","cssSelectorsEnabled","devicename","rotatable","takesScreenshot"] are not standard capabilities and should have an extension prefix
2019-02-25 19:52:14:601 [BaseDriver] Number capability passed in as string. Functionality may be compromised.
2019-02-25 19:52:14:603 [Appium] Creating new AndroidDriver (v4.7.0) session
2019-02-25 19:52:14:603 [Appium] Capabilities:
2019-02-25 19:52:14:604 [Appium]   apppackage: com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines
2019-02-25 19:52:14:604 [Appium]   cssSelectorsEnabled: true
2019-02-25 19:52:14:604 [Appium]   devicename: android
2019-02-25 19:52:14:604 [Appium]   platformName: android
2019-02-25 19:52:14:605 [Appium]   rotatable: true
2019-02-25 19:52:14:605 [Appium]   takesScreenshot: true
2019-02-25 19:52:14:605 [Appium]   app: /Users/magantimurthy/CCI_Mobile_UI_Tests/src/app-release.apk
2019-02-25 19:52:14:605 [Appium]   appActivity: com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines.MainActivity
2019-02-25 19:52:14:605 [Appium]   appWaitActivity: com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines.MainActivity
2019-02-25 19:52:14:605 [Appium]   autoGrantPermissions: true
2019-02-25 19:52:14:606 [Appium]   clearSystemFiles: true
2019-02-25 19:52:14:607 [Appium]   deviceName: Android
2019-02-25 19:52:14:608 [Appium]   eventTimings: true
2019-02-25 19:52:14:608 [Appium]   fullReset: true
2019-02-25 19:52:14:608 [Appium]   newCommandTimeout: 200000
2019-02-25 19:52:14:611 [BaseDriver] W3C capabilities {"alwaysMatch":{"appium:app... and MJSONWP desired capabilities {"app":"/Users/magantimurth... were provided
2019-02-25 19:52:14:611 [BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {"alwaysMatch":{"appium:app...
2019-02-25 19:52:14:613 [BaseDriver] Number capability passed in as string. Functionality may be compromised.
2019-02-25 19:52:14:614 [BaseDriver] Boolean capability passed in as string. Functionality may be compromised.
2019-02-25 19:52:14:615 [BaseDriver] Capability 'autoGrantPermissions' changed from string to boolean. This may cause unexpected behavior
2019-02-25 19:52:14:616 [BaseDriver] Capability 'newCommandTimeout' changed from string ('200000') to integer (200000). This may cause unexpected behavior
2019-02-25 19:52:14:619 [BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by appium: apppackage, cssSelectorsEnabled, devicename, rotatable, takesScreenshot.
2019-02-25 19:52:14:621 [BaseDriver] Session created with session id: fea2c61d-37eb-4198-b4a8-e833dbc143e9
2019-02-25 19:52:14:688 [AndroidDriver] Java version is: 1.8.0_192
2019-02-25 19:52:14:690 [ADB] Checking whether adb is present
2019-02-25 19:52:14:695 [ADB] Found 1 'build-tools' folders under '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk' (newest first):
2019-02-25 19:52:14:695 [ADB]     /Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3
2019-02-25 19:52:14:696 [ADB] Using adb from /Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
2019-02-25 19:52:14:696 [AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
2019-02-25 19:52:14:696 [ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
2019-02-25 19:52:14:697 [ADB] Getting connected devices...
2019-02-25 19:52:14:703 [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
2019-02-25 19:52:14:704 [AndroidDriver] Using device: 988a1643484534495a
2019-02-25 19:52:14:705 [ADB] Setting device id to 988a1643484534495a
2019-02-25 19:52:14:707 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
2019-02-25 19:52:14:789 [ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 26
2019-02-25 19:52:14:790 [ADB] Device API level: 26
2019-02-25 19:52:14:790 [AndroidDriver] Consider setting 'automationName' capability to 'uiautomator2' on Android >= 6, since UIAutomator framework is not maintained anymore by the OS vendor.
2019-02-25 19:52:14:792 [BaseDriver] Using local app '/Users/magantimurthy/CCI_Mobile_UI_Tests/src/app-release.apk'
2019-02-25 19:52:14:793 [AndroidDriver] Checking whether app is actually present
2019-02-25 19:52:14:794 [AndroidDriver] Starting Android session
2019-02-25 19:52:14:794 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a wait-for-device'
2019-02-25 19:52:14:802 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell echo ping'
2019-02-25 19:52:14:839 [AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to device...
2019-02-25 19:52:14:840 [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.settings
2019-02-25 19:52:14:841 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
2019-02-25 19:52:14:933 [ADB] 'io.appium.settings' is installed
2019-02-25 19:52:14:933 [ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.settings'
2019-02-25 19:52:14:934 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
2019-02-25 19:52:15:024 [ADB] Checking whether aapt is present
2019-02-25 19:52:15:025 [ADB] Using aapt from /Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/aapt
2019-02-25 19:52:15:032 [ADB] The version code of the installed 'io.appium.settings' is greater than the application version code (17 > 13)
2019-02-25 19:52:15:034 [ADB] There is no need to install/upgrade '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/io.appium.settings/apks/settings_apk-debug.apk'
2019-02-25 19:52:15:035 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell ps'
2019-02-25 19:52:15:171 [AndroidDriver] io.appium.settings is already running. There is no need to reset its permissions.
2019-02-25 19:52:15:171 [ADB] Device API level: 26
2019-02-25 19:52:15:172 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell appops set io.appium.settings android\:mock_location allow'
2019-02-25 19:52:15:278 [AndroidDriver] setDeviceLanguageCountry requires language or country.
2019-02-25 19:52:15:279 [AndroidDriver] Got language: 'null' and country: 'null'
2019-02-25 19:52:15:280 [Logcat] Starting logcat capture
2019-02-25 19:52:15:338 [ADB] Getting device platform version
2019-02-25 19:52:15:338 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
2019-02-25 19:52:15:381 [ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 8.0.0
2019-02-25 19:52:15:382 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell wm size'
2019-02-25 19:52:15:818 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell getprop ro.product.model'
2019-02-25 19:52:15:861 [ADB] Current device property 'ro.product.model': SM-G955U
2019-02-25 19:52:15:861 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell getprop ro.product.manufacturer'
2019-02-25 19:52:15:913 [ADB] Current device property 'ro.product.manufacturer': samsung
2019-02-25 19:52:15:914 [AndroidDriver] Parsing package and activity from app manifest
2019-02-25 19:52:15:915 [ADB] Using apkanalyzer from /Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/apkanalyzer
2019-02-25 19:52:15:916 [ADB] Starting '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/apkanalyzer' with args ["-h","manifest","print","/Users/magantimurthy/CCI_Mobile_UI_Tests/src/app-release.apk"]
2019-02-25 19:52:16:621 [ADB] Package name: 'com.aa.mobileCCIv4'
2019-02-25 19:52:16:622 [ADB] Main activity name: 'com.aa.mobileCCIv4.MainActivity'
2019-02-25 19:52:16:622 [AndroidDriver] Parsed package and activity are: com.aa.mobileCCIv4/com.aa.mobileCCIv4.MainActivity
2019-02-25 19:52:16:622 [ADB] Uninstalling com.aa.mobileCCIv4
2019-02-25 19:52:16:622 [ADB] Getting install status for com.aa.mobileCCIv4
2019-02-25 19:52:16:622 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell dumpsys package com.aa.mobileCCIv4'
2019-02-25 19:52:16:699 [ADB] 'com.aa.mobileCCIv4' is not installed
2019-02-25 19:52:16:699 [ADB] com.aa.mobileCCIv4 was not uninstalled, because it was not present on the device
2019-02-25 19:52:16:700 [ADB] Getting install status for com.aa.mobileCCIv4
2019-02-25 19:52:16:700 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell dumpsys package com.aa.mobileCCIv4'
2019-02-25 19:52:16:753 [ADB] 'com.aa.mobileCCIv4' is not installed
2019-02-25 19:52:16:753 [AndroidDriver] Running full reset on 'com.aa.mobileCCIv4' (reinstall)
2019-02-25 19:52:16:754 [ADB] Device API level: 26
2019-02-25 19:52:16:754 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a install -r -g /Users/magantimurthy/CCI_Mobile_UI_Tests/src/app-release.apk'
2019-02-25 19:52:22:481 [ADB] Install command stdout: Success
2019-02-25 19:52:22:482 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell rm -rf /data/local/tmp/strings.json'
2019-02-25 19:52:22:536 [AndroidDriver] Extracting strings from apk
2019-02-25 19:52:22:536 [AndroidDriver] /Users/magantimurthy/CCI_Mobile_UI_Tests/src/app-release.apk
2019-02-25 19:52:22:536 [AndroidDriver] null
2019-02-25 19:52:22:537 [AndroidDriver] /var/folders/96/1jt5x98s0cj7kwbtbkcd4vmr0000gn/T/com.aa.mobileCCIv4
2019-02-25 19:52:22:537 [ADB] Extracting strings from for language: default
2019-02-25 19:52:22:591 [ADB] Successfully extracted 67 strings from '/Users/magantimurthy/CCI_Mobile_UI_Tests/src/app-release.apk' resources for '(default)' configuration
2019-02-25 19:52:22:596 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a push /var/folders/96/1jt5x98s0cj7kwbtbkcd4vmr0000gn/T/com.aa.mobileCCIv4/strings.json /data/local/tmp'
2019-02-25 19:52:22:612 [AndroidBootstrap] Watching for bootstrap disconnect
2019-02-25 19:52:22:613 [ADB] Forwarding system: 4724 to device: 4724
2019-02-25 19:52:22:613 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a forward tcp\:4724 tcp\:4724'
2019-02-25 19:52:22:620 [UiAutomator] Starting UiAutomator
2019-02-25 19:52:22:620 [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'starting'
2019-02-25 19:52:22:620 [UiAutomator] Parsing uiautomator jar
2019-02-25 19:52:22:621 [UiAutomator] Found jar name: 'AppiumBootstrap.jar'
2019-02-25 19:52:22:621 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a push /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/bootstrap/bin/AppiumBootstrap.jar /data/local/tmp/'
2019-02-25 19:52:22:638 [ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
2019-02-25 19:52:22:639 [ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator
2019-02-25 19:52:22:639 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell ps'
2019-02-25 19:52:22:791 [ADB] No 'uiautomator' process has been found
2019-02-25 19:52:22:791 [UiAutomator] Starting UIAutomator
2019-02-25 19:52:22:792 [ADB] Creating ADB subprocess with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","988a1643484534495a","shell","uiautomator","runtest","AppiumBootstrap.jar","-c","io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap","-e","pkg","com.aa.mobileCCIv4","-e","disableAndroidWatchers",false,"-e","acceptSslCerts",false]
2019-02-25 19:52:23:253 [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'online'
2019-02-25 19:52:23:257 [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Loading json...
2019-02-25 19:52:23:257 [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] json loading complete.
2019-02-25 19:52:23:257 [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
2019-02-25 19:52:23:259 [AndroidBootstrap] Android bootstrap socket is now connected
2019-02-25 19:52:23:260 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell dumpsys window'
2019-02-25 19:52:23:264 [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Client connected
2019-02-25 19:52:23:302 [AndroidDriver] Screen already unlocked, doing nothing
2019-02-25 19:52:23:303 [ADB] Device API level: 26
2019-02-25 19:52:23:303 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell am start -W -n com.aa.mobileCCIv4/com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines.MainActivity -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000'
2019-02-25 19:52:23:609 [ADB] We tried to start an activity that doesn't exist, retrying with '.com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines.MainActivity' activity name
2019-02-25 19:52:23:609 [ADB] Device API level: 26
2019-02-25 19:52:23:610 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell am start -W -n com.aa.mobileCCIv4/.com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines.MainActivity -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000'
2019-02-25 19:52:23:912 [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
2019-02-25 19:52:23:914 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell am force-stop com.aa.mobileCCIv4'
2019-02-25 19:52:24:008 [ADB] Pressing the HOME button
2019-02-25 19:52:24:008 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell input keyevent 3'
2019-02-25 19:52:24:549 [ADB] Uninstalling com.aa.mobileCCIv4
2019-02-25 19:52:24:549 [ADB] Getting install status for com.aa.mobileCCIv4
2019-02-25 19:52:24:549 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell dumpsys package com.aa.mobileCCIv4'
2019-02-25 19:52:24:590 [ADB] 'com.aa.mobileCCIv4' is installed
2019-02-25 19:52:24:590 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell am force-stop com.aa.mobileCCIv4'
2019-02-25 19:52:24:641 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a uninstall com.aa.mobileCCIv4'
2019-02-25 19:52:25:099 [ADB] 'adb uninstall com.aa.mobileCCIv4' command output: Success
2019-02-25 19:52:25:099 [ADB] com.aa.mobileCCIv4 was successfully uninstalled
2019-02-25 19:52:25:100 [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
2019-02-25 19:52:25:104 [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
2019-02-25 19:52:25:105 [UiAutomator] Shutting down UiAutomator
2019-02-25 19:52:25:105 [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopping'
2019-02-25 19:52:25:107 [UiAutomator] UiAutomator shut down normally
2019-02-25 19:52:25:107 [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
2019-02-25 19:52:25:108 [ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
2019-02-25 19:52:25:108 [ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator
2019-02-25 19:52:25:108 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell ps'
2019-02-25 19:52:25:267 [ADB] No 'uiautomator' process has been found
2019-02-25 19:52:25:267 [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
2019-02-25 19:52:25:268 [Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
2019-02-25 19:52:25:269 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell am force-stop io.appium.unlock'
2019-02-25 19:52:25:326 [AndroidDriver] App was not copied, so not deleting
2019-02-25 19:52:25:327 [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1551124345327 (13:52:25 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time))
2019-02-25 19:52:25:348 [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Cannot start the 'com.aa.mobileCCIv4' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.aa.mobileCCIv4' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: Activity name '.com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines.MainActivity' used to start the app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity
2019-02-25 19:52:25:349 [W3C]     at ADB.apkUtilsMethods.startApp (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/tools/apk-utils.js:144:11)
2019-02-25 19:52:25:364 [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 10769 ms - 1619
2019-02-25 19:52:25:364 [HTTP]
```

Comment: Looks like your main activity cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

In logs, it clearly mentioned that main activity does not exist.

```
2019-02-25 19:52:23:303 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell am start -W -n com.aa.mobileCCIv4/com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines.MainActivity -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000'
2019-02-25 19:52:23:609 [ADB] We tried to start an activity that doesn't exist, retrying with '.com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines.MainActivity' activity name
2019-02-25 19:52:23:609 [ADB] Device API level: 26
2019-02-25 19:52:23:610 [ADB] Running '/Users/magantimurthy/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 988a1643484534495a shell am start -W -n com.aa.mobileCCIv4/.com.aa.dev.AmericanAirlines.MainActivity -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000'
2019-02-25 19:52:23:912 [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
```

Please cross check your main activity and replace with correct one.You can check how you can find the main activity and app package.

http://www.automationtestinghub.com/apppackage-and-appactivity-name/

Hope it help.

Comment: Kindly accept answer if it solves your problem to help community.

Comment: App is installed but never opening and so the reason for failure of main activity. It gets uninstalled automatically too

Comment: That’s what I have mentioned that check your main activity and try again.

Comment: @sri I have added in my answer that how you can check main activity.

Comment: the same framework is working fine with Windows machine but not with MAC machine. Initially , it used to work in MAC also but after updaing few softwares i could see that MAC is not working